# What is the statement query

Tags: mysql

Find the course with the second maximum number of prerequisites. You should return the result as the name of the course and the number of the prerequisites in this question. Please consider that there might be some courses, which may not have any prerequisites.

prereq table

| course_id      | prereq_id      |

| BIO-301        | BIO-101        |

| BIO-399        | BIO-101        |

| CS-190         | CS-101         |

| CS-315         | CS-101         |

| CS-319         | CS-101         |

| CS-347         | CS-101         |

| EE-202         | EE-181         |

| FIN-201        | MTH-101        |

| MTH-102        | MTH-101        |

| MTH-221        | MTH-101        |

| PHY-101        | MTH-101        |

| MTH-201        | MTH-102        |

| MTH-221        | MTH-102        |

| PHY-550        | MTH-102        |

| PHY-550        | MTH-221        |

| MU-199         | MU-101         |

| CS-319         | PHY-101        |

| EE-181         | PHY-101        |

| EE-202         | PHY-101        |

| PHY-550        | PHY-101        |

| NULL           | NULL           |

Comment: this is not a place for you to get your homework done by someone else. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic unless you clearly state 1. what your question is. 2. what is the problem you are having. and 3. show what you have tried so far, no one will help you out on this

Comment: However, if you post what you think the correct answer is, someone might tell you if anything is wrong with it!

Comment: it is not homework i am studyıng mysql and i found this. i did this SELECT  ( SELECT count(course_id) from prereq where course_id='BIO-301' as count_1) @khuderm

Comment: Absolute rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with select substring and select max query. For your reference, you can see this

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php

You can use this query to solve your problem :

```
select course_id, prereq_id from prereq_table where substring(prereq_id,5,1)=(select max(substring(prereq_id,5,1)) from prereq_table)
```

I fill my table with this

[image]

and by using the query above, it will return this

[image]

Comment: Can you simplifie your explaination to me about your question above? Maybe i got some missunderstanding because of my english is not really good